# How to resolve this error : Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1 at JSON.parse in angular

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

This is the error I get when I call the backend service

[image: it's the error when i done the call to backend:]

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse(<anonymous>)
    at ApplypositionComponent.push../src/app/applyposition/applyposition.component.ts.ApplypositionComponent.submit (applyposition.component.ts:144)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (ApplypositionComponent.html:75)
    at handleEvent (core.js:23107)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:24177)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:23904)
    at dispatchEvent (core.js:20556)
    at core.js:22046
    at SafeSubscriber.schedulerFn [as _next] (core.js:13527)
    at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:196)
```

this is my service:

```
postCurriculum(curriculum: FileData): Observable<any> {
    const headers = this.auth.getHeadersCurriculum();
    console.log("post", curriculum)
    return 
        this.http.post(this.fnBaseUrl, curriculum, {
            headers: headers   
    })   
}
```

and here i call the method

```
this.anagrService.postCurriculum(this.filedata).subscribe(
    response => {
})
```

from postman there's no problem by from angular,typescript i got this error when i passed the file object with status 200 but i have error..
help me please

Comment: What is `this.http`? Are you passing in `Content-Type: application/json` as headers? If you look at your browser's Developer Tools' **Network** tab, what is the _Response_ you get from the server to this POST request?

Comment: Can you post your HTML file, I see that you have a problem in line 75 of ApplypositionComponent.html.

Comment: @bjdose the HTML error is probably because he clicked some Submit button that then calls the .ts file at line 144, which is the next part of the traceback. It doesn't matter to a JSON parse error... The server is simply not sending back correct JSON data.

Comment: @RobinDeSchepper how can i resolve that problem i send file with type Object

Comment: @cubrr yes I'm passing application/json i received status 200

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
 private jsonHeaders = {
    accept: 'application/json'
  };

postCurriculum(curriculum: FileData): Observable<any> {
    const headers = this.auth.getHeadersCurriculum();
    console.log("post", curriculum)
    return 
        this.http.post<any>(this.fnBaseUrl, curriculum, {
            headers: this.jsonHeaders
    }) ;  
}
```